# What is safe graphics mode?

Tags: boot, graphics, uefi

On Ubuntu 19.04 and all its official flavors I observed that if I boot the LiveUSB in UEFI mode, there are options for live session and installation with **safe graphics** written beside them. However these options aren't available in legacy mode.

[image]

So, what is the purpose of this **safe graphics** mode? Is there any specific reason why they included in 19.04 and not on previous releases such as 16.04, 18.04 and 18.10?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While @marosg answer is excellent, I just want to add..

`nomodeset` parameter is highly in use since the previous releases and lot of people are looking for a workaround or solution in the web while their first attempt failed due to graphics problem..

While there are answers how to edit the kernel parameter while booting the *Live USB*.

*With the addition of this boot entry, it gives the user a fast way to try Ubuntu/ Install Ubuntu here onwards..*

As I have tried to view the parameters for these new entries...
it just added `nomodeset` no other parameters other than default.

Please have a look on below images..

Try Ubuntu without Installing
[image]

Try Ubuntu without Installing (safe Graphics)
[image]

Install Ubuntu
[image]

Install Ubuntu (safe Graphics)
[image]

Here are few links to previous Questions about `nomodeset`.

- [How to set nomodeset GRUB2 before I've installed Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431534/how-to-set-nomodeset-grub2-before-ive-installed-ubuntu)
- [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)
- [Nomodeset Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83642/nomodeset-installation)
- [Black Screen without nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086453/black-screen-without-nomodeset)
- [How to boot without 'nomodeset'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128128/how-to-boot-without-nomodeset)
- [Is nomodeset still required?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required)

Answer (score 14):

Special reason why they include it is called progress :) There are cases when system cannot correctly initialize graphics card and after boot you get just a black screen. Safe graphics mode sets boot parameters the way which allow to boot and be able to login and correct things. If it works ok it will be probably included in later releases as well.

Comment: I know this is old, but I just installed a second gpu in the 3rd PCIe x16 slot (slow, but only necessary to run office and dev stuff in Linux) on my x570 e-gaming mainboard (Asus). I wanted to avoid having the main GPU for games resort to x8 due to sharing the bandwidth with this card. This ffx is just for visually simple tasks, so chooser x4 will suffice I think. "Ubuntu (Safe graphics)" worked here, the regular "Ubuntu" did not.