# Why doesn't Ubuntu work on my 2011 iMac?

Tags: boot, mac, crash

I have a 2011 iMac that I wanted to use with Ubuntu.  When booting the installer from a USB/SD card, it would always crash on the normal installer.  Screen just went black.  So I tried the "Safe Graphics" mode or whatever it was called.

Installation went great.  Detected my WiFi, etc.

Now that installation is complete, the computer won't boot.  I only get a black screen.  Not sure why the "safe mode" worked and not the normal mode.  And, I tried holding down the left shift to boot into safe mode again but nothing but black screen.

Any idea what I can do?  I'm using the newest version of Ubuntu, btw.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I booted into the installer again but this time, I choose Try Ubuntu.  Also, I have to select "safe graphics".  But everything works as long as I use Safe Graphics.  How can I always use this mode?

Comment: Are you able to boot into your bios, or is the screen black at post?

Comment: This is a Mac.  No BIOS (that I know of) to boot into.

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138137/what-is-safe-graphics-mode)? That should get you sorted and explain what's going on. It's *nomodeset* that you're looking for.

Comment: Yep, I found that.  Then later I found a post that helped me out (see my answer).  It's working now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with Christian's answer here:  https://askubuntu.com/a/941322/144825

Basically, I had to boot off the Live CD and mount the installed Linux.  Then, update the Grub config with `nomodeset`, etc.