# Firmware update for SSD on Windows messed up my Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

Yesterday, I had to install some firmware updates from my Windows partition, which got completed successfully. I loaded up Ubuntu to check if everything was alright after the update but when I did, my screen went black and it started showing me some colorful dots on the upper half of my screen. It loaded up Ubuntu when I pressed the power button again, but it reloads the page a few times before I can actually login

I want to know how I can make my Ubuntu boot up normal and smooth again.

A picture of my issue is given below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCLFn.jpg

I'm using a Lenovo Y540 with a 1TB SSD running Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 20

Comment: @nmath I’m describing what my system is doing. I want to know how I can fix my boot up of Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm suggesting that it's not clear what you need help with.  When you say *"Everything seemed alright but now whenever I try to change my screen brightness"*, it would seem that you don't have any problems with booting, but you have a problem with screen brightness.  You should edit your question (and the title) to reflect this and to add detail.  Please read [How to Ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on how to provide detail to increase your chances that someone will recognize the problem and be able to propose a solution

Comment: @nmath Please take a look and let me know if It’s better described. I apologise if I’m unable to describe it properly, I’m really new to Ubuntu and don’t know what I’m facing issues with

Comment: @nmath I suspect that those colourful dots are error messages which are not being displayed properly. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu after the update but I was facing the same issues again, but I loaded up Ubuntu in safe graphics mode during setup and it was working perfectly. Do you how I can default to that mode? Also is there a way to rollback to previous firmware update?

Comment: @nmath Ok I’ll upload a picture

Comment: Have you tried flashing back to the previous SSD firmware version? Do you know the version number you used to have and the new version number? Do you know the make and model number of the SSD? EG I have a Samsung Pro 960 and know a little of it's "quirks" with firmware. That said I haven't updated firmware since 2017 when it was purchased because there were no problems to fix. What problems were you trying to fix by upgrading firmware? Providing information like this in your question might help you come to a faster resolution with advise from others in similar environment.

Comment: @nmath I ran get-physical disk and this is the output. Micron MTFDHBA1T0TCK 0000_0000_0000_0001_00A0_7519_2340_0262. SSD - this is what I'm using. Also I'm using a lenovo laptop and it was forcing me to update my firmware, there werent any issues as such

Comment: @nmath I have added the picture as a link as the file size was too large. Please check it out

Comment: I'm sorry I don't recognize anything in that screenshot.  It looks like a glitch. Unfortunately it doesn't represent any information about the problem.  Have you searched about this to see if anyone else has a similar issue after firmware updates? Maybe someone else has been able to better pinpoint the issue

Comment: @nmath Do you know how I can use Ubuntu in safe graphics mode? It seemed to work well in that mode.

Comment: How did you do it before?  Is there a problem preventing you from applying the solutions from questions like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138137/what-is-safe-graphics-mode

Comment: @nmath Although I'm quite sure I installed it in safe graphics mode but I'm not 100% certain. Is there a way to check that. Also I don't see any option to load ubuntu safe graphics after installation.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you try to do more research on your own. It's unlikely that you're the only person who has documented this behavior. Since you can interact with your device and see what's on the screen, you have the ability to generate more relevant search terms about your issue. And you can evaluate what you find, and search again about terms you don't understand in your findings.  This is more than we can do in 500 character replies to each other every few hours... Then edit your question and share your research with us.  Tell us what you learned and where you are still stuck.

Comment: @nmath I was able to fix my boot up. I added nomodeset argument along with quiet splash in grub_cmdline_default and updated grub. I’m not sure what that does. Then I also auto installed the graphic drivers.

Comment: I used sudo Ubuntu-drivers autoinstall and then reboot