# I can't even try the live USB (AMD/ATI)

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, amd-graphics

I tried from the live USB Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS and Lubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (both desktop, downloaded from their official sites).
Ubuntu live USB: I can't see anything at all, only stripes.
Lubuntu works fine live **with safe graphics mode on** but after installing the screen looks with stripes too.
Is there a way to add the driver to the live Ubuntu or Lubuntu USB stick from a windows machine?
I'm a total newbie so any kind of help will be appreciated.

AMD/ATI Super Sumo Radeon HD 6410D. AMD A4-3300 Processor.

Comment: Hey Victoria Samotracia! *"...all I can see is stripes"* Can you please add a photo of the stripes in the question such that we can understand the problem more clearly? BTW, I suggest you to go through the [tour] page.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm sorry, I can't take a screenshot.

Comment: If you can take a photo with your smartphone and share the photo, it might be helpful.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have access.

Comment: If the live disk works but it fails after install, then an incompatible driver is being installed that isn't being used by the live disk.   Sometimes you can boot the installed system with nomodeset and try `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS downloaded from here and Lubuntu 20.04 LTS downloaded from the official page.

Comment: I can use Lubuntu live USB with the 'Safe graphics mode'  option but I don't have the 'Install third party software' option so I can't see anything after install. In Ubuntu I don't have a safe graphics option so I can't even use the live USB.

Comment: I'll suggest switching to text terminal (ctrl+alt+f4 for example) and login there.  I'd then `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and see if additional drivers are included.  Later releases of Ubuntu Desktop provide many drivers that aren't included on Lubuntu media, so Lubuntu will use more basic kernel modules (a driver is a kernel module) and this command will ask the system to look for better drivers for your hardware. It's what @user10489 suggested hours ago  (here I mean on an installed system, not the *live* medium)

Comment: 20.04.2 LTS from the official site and Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS also from the official site. Sorry but I can't edit previous answer after 5 minutes.

Comment: If you had to use safe graphics mode on the live disk, you'll have to do the same thing on the installed system, except it's not a direct option in the menu.  I'll see if I can turn this into an answer later.  It would have been helpful to include this critical detail in your original question.  Once you boot the installed system either in text mode or in safe graphics mode, you should try to install better drivers by one of these methods.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

actually yes, but that seems not to be that straight forward. As you call yourself a newbie I recommend not doing it. If Lubuntu works fine this might not to be a driver issue perhaps since both should use the same base/kernel. The AMD driver comes with the kernel itself. Maybe you might install Lubuntu update(!) and install the DE (desktop env) you prefer such as GNOME38.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Lubuntu 20 Live USB worked fine but after install I had the same problem (can't see the screen, just blue stripes).

Comment: That sounds odd. Which driver are you using? The Mesa driver?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the default graphics driver is not working correctly with your video card.  The safe graphics mode disables the incompatible part of the video driver, but leaves you with no video acceleration.

As a temporary fix, you can enable safe graphics mode for the installed ubuntu by selecting an entry in the grub menu and editing it (press e) to add `nomodeset` to the `linux` line.  See [What is safe graphics mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138137/what-is-safe-graphics-mode)
Note that this only changes the in memory version of the grub menu, this is temporary only.  If this doesn't work, it is possible to completely disable graphics and force text mode via a similar edit.

Once you have booted into a usable video mode (graphics or text), you then need to install a video driver appropriate for your video card.  The command `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` should do the hard work of selecting the correct driver and installing it.  (Note that this will try to download drivers from internet, so your network must be working for this to help.)

After successfully installing the driver, you will need to reboot.  If everything works, you shouldn't need to use nomodeset again.

Comment: Thank you. `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`  gives me "no drivers found for installation" I also tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` followed by  `sudo apt upgrade` It downloaded something but after boot I had the same problem with the screen.