# Ubuntu setup stuck at "Preparing ubuntu-drivers" (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: system-installation

The title is the question, I cant install ubuntu because, at the 4th step, it gets stuck on "preparing ubuntu-drivers"

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I do not know what machine you are installing, but either skip installing 'ubuntu-drivers' or update your BIOS first, may work.

Comment: You must use [safe graphics mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138137/what-is-safe-graphics-mode).

Answer (score 2):

Select quit and try again. The second time it worked for me.

Comment: Me to, I did not have to uncheck third-party software.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncheck the *Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-
Fi hardware and additional media formats* option in the **Updates and other software** screen of the Ubuntu installer.  Maybe you can click back to this screen, but probably not if you're stuck. In that case you need to exit from the Ubuntu installer and start it again, this time unchecking the *Install third-party software...* option as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]