# trying to dual boot - unknown chipset nouveau issue with no options to install driver using grub

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I am trying to dual boot my pc with windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. I used both balena etcher and rufus for making the flash drive, same problem for both. My flash drive has 32 gb so it is fully fitted on there. I start the pc with the usb inside after selecting the right priority in the BIOS.
I already have windows installed and am trying to add the ubuntu version mentioned.
When starting the pc I see a very short error message which I cannot read because it immediately dissapears and then get the following menu with the following options

```
Try or install Ubuntu
Ubuntu(safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufactureres)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware settings
```

When doing any of the last 3 options it just starts to windows.
I did not try the second option "Ubuntu" and when doing try or install ubuntu I get the following error message with a black screen

```
[ numbers] nouveau numbers: unknown chipset (numbers)
```

What exactly can I do? I found one stack overflow where they mentioned that it is because the driver is not supported and I have to install it. They mentioned enabling networking and then selecting dpkg, however I cannot find a place to do that. I can then also not open any terminal somewhere to install the driver.

Comment: Use the second option "Ubuntu(safe graphics)". Then install the Nvidia driver onto Ubuntu

Comment: what exactly does the second option do?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1138137/1004020 . It's for installing Ubuntu when it has a problem with your (usually Nvidia) GPU. Once you finish installing, you can install Nvidia's official driver

Comment: so when I install the driver using command line for example on the graphics version, can I then restart the pc and use the normal option? Because I tried using the graphics version and "try ubuntu" installed the driver using the terminal but then when I restarted my pc and did the first option it gave the same error.

Comment: You should not see the same menu of options when you reboot. You need to eject and remove the installation media

Comment: so I should not only do try ubuntu but also install it with the save grahics?

Comment: Why? If "try ubuntu" works then use it. Only if it doesn't work, use "safe graphics".

Comment: the problem was that that the first option "try and install" does not work. The save graphics does work but I assumed that was just for installing the driver so that after the driver works you should still use the "try and install" option. Since I want the optimal version and not the save version. But I selected "save graphics" then selected "try ubuntu" and then installed the drivers. After I did not want to install ubuntu using save graphics so I restarted my pc but then I tried the "try and install" option again and it did not work. So should i just install ubuntu using the "save graphics"?

Comment: I guess so. I've never had to personally use safe graphics. If the menu goes "safe graphics" > "try ubuntu" then you can use that. Just remember to remove the USB or CD before rebooting so that you don't see the "try ubuntu" option again after installing